# Querying Many-to-One in Mysql

Tags: mysql, many-to-one

The following image illustrates how my database is organized:

[a busy cat http://akplebani.com/graphic.png](http://akplebani.com/graphic.png)

What I'm looking for is a **single** query wich results gives me **coordinate_name**, **title_project**, **title_solution** and **name_client**, based on coordinate **date**.

I'm trying something like this:

```
SELECT coordinate_name, title_project, title_solution, name_client FROM coordinate NATURAL JOIN client WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nut sure exactly how you want to define all your JOINS (i.e. INNER JOINS, OUTER JOINS, etc.) but this should get you started

```
SELECT
co.coordinate_name,
cl.name_client,
s.title_solution,
p.title_project
FROM
coordinate AS co
INNER JOIN project AS p ON co.project_id_project = p.id_project
INNER JOIN solution AS s ON p.solution_id_solution = s.id_solution
INNER JOIN client AS cl ON s.client_id_client = cl.id_client
WHERE
co.date BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Comment: Mike, thanks for the answer! I will be making some tests by the way you suggested.